# Inconsistent Rails database schema generation for boolean fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, boolean

Rails version = 2.3.8

When comparing the schemas of two of my sites, each with an almost identical codebase, I noticed something very strange. For the exact same table, the schema of one site shows:

```
t.integer  "member_feed",   :limit => 1, :default => 1
```

and for the other:

```
t.boolean  "member_feed",   :default => true
```

There was no difference in the way the two were created. In fact, the first one was actually extracted from the second when the site was created. This first schema had at least 40 different cases where boolean was displayed incorrectly, and I had to go in and change each one with a `change_column` migration. Note that there is definitely a difference in functionality when boolean is not explicitly defined.

Anybody have an idea as to what may be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use different databases for each (PostgreSQL, SQLite3, MySQL, etc)?  Can you post the migration that creates that field in the DB?

Comment: MySQL for both. There was only one migration in all, containing `t.boolean :member_feed, :default => true`. The problem site's database was generated by running `rake db:schema:load' using the original site's schema.

Comment: @modulaaron - did my answer help you understand th issue? If so - would you please accept my answer? It'll also help you improve your answer-rate :)

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you run migrations from different Operating Systems. It's not rails' mysql that's at fault, but *actual* mysql.

Some versions of it just don't store the fact that there are limits and other flags... usually ones that actually have a built-in boolean class thus removing the necessity for a limit => 1  (you'll find it also failing to store some versions of "precision" for decimal values too)

The problem comes in because that mysql assumes that all other versions have a built-in class... and of course they don't.

This is an integrated-systems bug that really can't be fixed. Sorry. :(